# When exactly does pg_stat_all_tables.last_autovacuum get updated?

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

I'm looking into issues with our autovacuum settings and trying to understand `last_autoanalyze` and `last_autovacuum` from the `pg_stat_all_tables`.

I understand autovacuum to work in an incremental way, compacting and cleaning up dead tuples in batches, then sleeping for a moment, etc. So what does `last_autovacuum` mean? Is it possible that autovacuum could be *mostly* working but that that timestamp might never get updated (e.g. because a tuple could not be removed)?

Many of the timestamps I see for our tables are old, even though I'm fairly sure I observed a running autovacuum thread on some of the tables.

**EDIT**:
If I'm unclear, my question is: does `last_autovacuum` mean...

- the time at which an incremental autovacuum process last finished up a chunk of work on this table and slept
- the time an autovacuum process worked its way to the very end of a table
- the above, but only if there were no tuples that could not be removed
- something else

Comment: Could you clarify a bit your question ? The `last_autovacuum` is `last time at which this table was vacuumed by the autovacuum daemon`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also wanted to know this, so I dug through the Postgres src code a bit to try and find out...

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ca3b37487be333a1d241dab1bbdd17a211a88f43/src/backend/catalog/system_views.sql#L584

```
pg_stat_get_last_autovacuum_time(C.oid) as last_autovacuum,
```

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ca3b37487be333a1d241dab1bbdd17a211a88f43/src/backend/utils/adt/pgstatfuncs.c#L267

```
result = tabentry->autovac_vacuum_timestamp;
```

https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/ca3b37487be333a1d241dab1bbdd17a211a88f43/src/include/pgstat.h#L740

```
TimestampTz autovac_vacuum_timestamp;   /* autovacuum initiated */
```

So, if I followed the code correctly, it appears that `last_autovacuum` timestamp is when the process **started**, not when it finished.

Answer (score 1):

The last_autovacuum is nothing but the last time at which the autovacuum daemon done the vacuuming process on tables

The **pg_stat_all_tables** view will contain one row for each table in the current database (including TOAST tables), showing statistics about accesses to that specific table

- the last_autovacuum will be update it timestamp only if dead tuples are removed for the respected table during vacuuming

For more information kindly refere postgresql stats collector page https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/monitoring-stats.html

Comment: So if last_autovacuum field is null, that's because  a) autovacuum process always decides that no tuples have to be removed from the table, AND/OR b) autovacuum process can't finish removing dead tuples. Am I right?

Comment: If the time of autovacuum is long - is it the time of beginning of operation or the end of operation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems last_autovacuum is the time vacuuming completed, because:
(0) timestamps are sometimes really close together:
2023-07-16 08:21:19.247452+00
2023-07-16 08:21:19.495501+00
(1) according to the docs one autovacuum is run on each database each autovacuum_naptime seconds.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM